# Counting specific nodes in linked list Java

Tags: java, list, count

I have to count nodes in Circular Doubly Linked List in interval [-100;100]. I know how to do that when i'm implementing a node. Here's code :

```
public void insert(int val){
        ....
        if((val >= -100) && (val <= 100)){
            number++;
        }
.....
```

But when i'm deleting a node at given position (pos), i have no idea how to check the value of that node, so i don't know if "number" stays the same or it decreases.
Here is code of deleting node:

```
public void deleteAtPos(int pos){
            if (pos == 1){
            if(size == 1){
                start = null;
                end = null;
                size = 0;
                number = 0;
                return;
            }
            start = start.getLinkNext();
            start.setLinkPrev(end);
            end.setLinkNext(start);
            size--;
            return;
        }
        if (pos == size){
            end = end.getLinkPrev();
            end.setLinkNext(start);
            start.setLinkPrev(end);
            size--; 
        }
        }
        Node ptr = start.getLinkNext();
        for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++){
            if (i == pos){
                Node p = ptr.getLinkPrev();
                Node n = ptr.getLinkNext();
                p.setLinkNext(n);
                n.setLinkPrev(p);
                size--;
                return;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getLinkNext();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean `how to check the value of that node` ? the linked list node should have a data accessor method `getData()`

Comment: Yes, i have that method but i don't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand , you can simply check the value of the node by adding

```
ptr.getval() or start.getval()   //depending on the value of pos(aasuming getval is your function to retrieve node data)
```